# How do I install qBittorrent from the tarball?

Tags: software-installation, compiling, install-from-source, qbittorrent

[Source Tarball](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qbittorrent/files/latest/download). I started with the instructions found in the "INSTALL" file found in the extracted tarball and after I typed `./configure` after which I received the error:

```
Configuring qbittorrent ...
Verifying Qt 4 build environment ... fail

Reason: There was an error compiling 'conf'.  See conf.log for details.

Be sure you have a proper Qt 4.0 build environment set up.  This means not
just Qt, but also a C++ compiler, a make tool, and any other packages
necessary for compiling C++ programs.

If you are certain everything is installed, then it could be that Qt 4 is not
being recognized or that a different version of Qt is being detected by
mistake (for example, this could happen if $QTDIR is pointing to a Qt 3
installation).  At least one of the following conditions must be satisfied:

 1) --qtdir is set to the location of Qt
 2) $QTDIR is set to the location of Qt
 3) QtCore is in the pkg-config database
 4) qmake is in the $PATH

This script will use the first one it finds to be true, checked in the above
order.  #3 and #4 are the recommended options.  #1 and #2 are mainly for
overriding the system configuration.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked the `conf.log` and it actually expects `libtorrent` to be available. The steps to be followed are here

https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/wiki/Compiling-qBittorrent-on-Debian-and-Ubuntu

I tried it myself and it works :)

Comment: I followed the guide you linked and I was A OK up til cd libtorrent
 at which point I received the error bash: cd: libtorrent: No such file or directory

Comment: What was the output of this step?

`svn co https://libtorrent.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/libtorrent/branches/RC_0_16/ libtorrent`

Comment: The program 'svn' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install subversion
oops rofl I oversaw this, I should probably run sudo apt-get install subversion. By the way how do I get the code I write in comments formatted the way your code is?

Comment: Updated the answer with the part of the same document which shows how to install required dependencies. Enclose the text with ` to highlight as code.

Comment: OK I did what you said as far as following that guide and I got up to (under Compiling qBittorrent (with the Qt4 graphical interface))  `./configure` at which point I received the same error as I put in my question. I have done all the building of dependencies mentioned in the guide but for some reason this didn't work.

Comment: Does your machine meet all the requirements mentioned here https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/wiki/Debian---Ubuntu-compilation#wiki-Required_dependencies? If Yes, please paste the contents of `conf.log`

Comment: `/usr/bin/moc-qt4 -DQT_WEBKIT -DHAVE_MODULES -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. conf4.cpp -o conf4.moc
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_WEBKIT -DHAVE_MODULES -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -o conf4.o conf4.cpp
In file included from conf4.cpp:703:0:
libboost.qcm:9:34: fatal error: libtorrent/version.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [conf4.o] Error 1`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8331/discussion-between-thefourtheye-and-brenton-horne)